# Can I have color ls output automatically if my TERM is "xterm-256color"?

Tags: terminal, environment-variables

Can I have automatic color output for `ls` if my `TERM` environment variable is set to `xterm-256color`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using bash, you could add `export CLICOLOR="YES"` to your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: GHAAAAA! I set the variable up wrong! I set it to `CLICOLORS`!

Comment: You can also make use of the `LS_COLORS` var to customize the colors

Answer (score 4):

Just for the sake of anyone who might come along and wonder how to restrict this to only when the TERM is a certain value, you could put something like this in your shell's "rc" file (.zshrc or .bashrc etc):

```
case "$TERM" in 

    xterm-256color)
        export CLICOLOR="YES"
    ;;

    *color|xterm*)
        export CLICOLOR="YES"
    ;;

    vt100)
        export CLICOLOR="NO"
    ;;

esac
```

Note that the 2nd example is just there to show why you might want to use 'case' instead of 'if/then': the ability to use wildcard matching and use multiple entries separated by |